# Lucene.NET MoreLikeThis Example

Tags: c#, lucene.net, morelikethis

Could anyone give an example of how to use the MoreLikeThis feature in Lucene.NET. I have searched online and cannot find a single example.

Comment: Did you find this? http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/

Comment: i think that one is Java

Comment: This is a port of the MoreLikeThis query.  http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/CSharp/Lucene/aimee/Aimee/Net/Search/Similar/MoreLikeThis.cs.htm.  Can you not understand java code?

Comment: And this is the offical port of it (https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/incubator/lucene.net/trunk/src/contrib/Queries/ ) . Same syntax.

Answer (score 2):

(Resurrecting an old question!)

As an example for Lucene.Net 2.9.4g:

```
var moreLikeThis = new Lucene.Net.Search.Similar.MoreLikeThis(indexReader);
moreLikeThis.SetAnalyzer(analyzer);
moreLikeThis.SetFieldNames(fieldNames);
moreLikeThis.SetStopWords(stopWords);
moreLikeThis.SetMinWordLen(2);
var query = moreLikeThis.Like(new System.IO.StringReader(similarity));
```

This generates a Lucene.Net.Search.Query object that can be used to search for documents that are similar to the text passed into the StringReader object.